# Circuit theory. Find the node voltages

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

How to solve the above question?

I cannot apply Kirchoff's current equation because of the presence of the dependent voltage source

Also, I am not able to apply supernode because of the 2 kOhm resistor in series. How should I go about it? Please help.

Comment: What current is going through the 1k resistor?

Comment: @Transistor \$ v_2/1000 \$ Amperes.

Comment: You can get the numerical value just by looking at that loop. What's the current on the other side of the loop? Then what's the current through the 1k resistor?

Comment: @Transistor 3 mAmperes

Comment: So, can you now work out \$ v_2 \$?

Answer (score 2):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgq9w0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

We also see that \$\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3=\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_2\$.

> Now, using those equations your problem can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is in series with the current source, meaning the voltage across the 1K resistor must be 1000*0.003, from there you solve the rest of the circuit

The step after this, as you know the V2 node would be how that current source is split between the 2K + voltage source and the 4K Resistor, if you need to, you can imagine it as 2 voltage sources with an ESR, both in parallel with each other.